# Facebook graph api Request header field authorization is not allowed

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm calling facebook graph api using ajax as follows,

```
             $.ajax({
                    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+accessToken,
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (response) {
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log('Error occurd while retrieving long live access token');
                    }
                });
```

But it shows error as follows,

```
Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

If I make the request using `postman` or using the browser it works fine. Appriciate any help to resolve this issue. I tried several answers regarding the  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the server side, but in this case I don't have the control over facebook side.

Comment: I see nothing in that code that would cause an `authorization` header to be send in the first place ...

Comment: found the issue. someone has configured `ajaxPrefilter` somewhere else in the code.